# How to hook up AWS RDS - Aurora with AWS Lambda Java function

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I am trying to hook up AWS RDS Aurora database with AWS Lambda Java function. For this, I am yet to see any concrete examples. I have seen some examples but they are non java.

I would also like to configure a mySQL DBMS tool with Aurora which I am not able to do :( Can someone help me with that as well. I have got the connection strings from https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-east-1#dbinstances.

Also, the code I am trying to connect to DB via Lambda Java is:

```
private Statement createConnection(Context context) {
    logger = context.getLogger();
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://HOSTNAME:3306";
        String username = "USERNAME";
        String password = "PASSWORD";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conn.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.log("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

And yes, this doesn't help as I always get null using the db instance config.

[image: Security groups added to db isntance]

Comment: Is your RDS inside a VPC? And is your Lambda function inside that VPC?

Comment: Adding to what dasmug asked as well, what is the security groups for both the RDS db and the Lambda function.

Comment: @strongjz RDS has all security groups added. There were 4. I also tried hooking it to SequelPro which fails as well

Comment: Added where? I meant in the question, what the vpc questions?

Comment: Updated in the original question with a screenshot.  @strongjz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS needs be in a security group that opens the DB port to the Security Group attached to the ENI of the lambda.

> To enable your Lambda function to access resources inside your private VPC, you must provide additional VPC-specific configuration
>   information that includes VPC subnet IDs and security group IDs. AWS
>   Lambda uses this information to set up elastic network interfaces
>   (ENIs) that enable your function to connect securely to other
>   resources within your private VPC.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html